# How to remove the space after references/bibliography title?

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, bibtex

After 'References' title and before the items list, there is a space between them, as shown in the following figure:

[image]

My code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}
\usepackage{expdlist}
\renewcommand{\refname}{\large 6. References}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

I successfully removed the space between the items list, but can't remove the space after the 'References' title. May I know how to remove the space in the red box?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Unless you provide some LaTeX code that shows how you build the bibliography, it's virtually impossible for readers of your posting to suggest LaTeX code that modifies your LaTeX code in a way that lets you achieve your formatting goals. To maximize your chances of getting useful advice, your LaTeX code should be not merely a code snippet but a *minimal working example*, i.e., something that starts with `\document` class, ends with `\end{document]`, and reproduces the formatting issue you're looking to solve.

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much for your reply. I have added the corresponding code.

Answer (score 3):

Since you use the `natbib` package, you could redefine its `\bibpreamble` macro to snug up the space between the bibliography header and the first bib item.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@misc{abc:3000,
  author = "A and B and C", title = "Thoughts", year = 3000}
@misc{xyz:3001,
  author = "X and Y and Z", title = "Thoughts", year = 3001}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,expdlist}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\renewcommand\bibpreamble{\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}} % choose a suitable vert. skip
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt} % no extra vert. space between bib items
\renewcommand{\refname}{\large 6. References}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! It works well! Thank you so much!

Comment: If one does not use bibtex what he do? thanks

Comment: @Student - What is your question about? E.g., how to create a bibliography? How to create citation call-outs to bibliographic entries? How to reduce the amount of vertical whitespace between the sectioning header and the first bibliographic entry? Please be specific.

Comment: How to reduce the amount of vertical whitespace between the sectioning header and the first bibliographic entry?

Comment: @Student - May I suggest you post a *new query*, in which you describe your document setup (including information about the document class you employ) and how you create the bibliography?

Comment: yes please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/691131/delete-the-word-r%c3%a9f%c3%a9rences-and-the-space-before-it

Comment: @Student - Please see the answer I just posted for your new query.