# delete the word ``Références'' and the space before it

Tags: spacing, bibliographies

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{article}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\newcommand\encercle[1]{%
    \unitlength1em%
    \begin{picture}(1.5,1.5)%
        \put(0.75,0.3){\circle{1.5}}% modifier 0.3 éventuellement
        \put(0,0){\parbox[b]{1.5em}{\centering#1}}%
    \end{picture}}


\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{calc}%pour encadrer un paragraphe
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.5cm}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{citeblue}{rgb}{0.00,0.00,0.60}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=citeblue, citecolor=citeblue, linkcolor=citeblue}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{\textcircled{\scriptsize #1}}
\makeatother
%------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}


\section{Articles préparés pendant la préparation de la thèse}
Durant la préparation de ma thèse, j'ai rédigé et publié 4 articles scientifiques, à savoir : 
\renewcommand{\bibname}{}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{s1}{J.G. Stampfli,} {The norm of derivation,} Pacific J. Math. 33 (1970), no. 3, 737-747.

\bibitem{s2}{J.G. Stampfli,} {The norm of derivation,} Pacific J. Math. 33 (1970), no. 3, 737-747.

\end{thebibliography}
\section{Articles publiés ou acceptés pour publication après la soutenance de la thèse}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{s3}{J.G. Stampfli,} {The norm of derivation,} Pacific J. Math. 33 (1970), no. 3, 737-747.

\bibitem{s4}{J.G. Stampfli,} {The norm of derivation,} Pacific J. Math. 33 (1970), no. 3, 737-747.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I want to delete the word ``Références'' and the space before it

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: There are two pairs of curly braces in `\bibitem{s3}{J.G. Stampfli,} {The norm of derivation,} Pacific J. Math. 33 (1970), no. 3, 737-747.` that do nothing useful, while creating pointless code clutter. I can see no reason for omitting the pointless curly braces, i.e., for writing `\bibitem{s3} J.G. Stampfli, The norm of derivation, Pacific J. Math. 33 (1970), no. 3, 737-747.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't just want to make the word "Références" invisible, right? Instead, you'd like to completely delete the unnumbered section-level header, no?

If that's the case, just add the instructions

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for '\patchcmd' macro
\patchcmd\thebibliography{\section*{\refname}}{}{}{}
```

to the preamble. This works because the `article` document class defines an environment called `thebibliography`. The `\patchcmd` directive shown above removes the instruction `\section*{\refname}` from that environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{article}
%% I've tried to streamline and de-cruft the preamble code

\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage{graphicx}
%%\usepackage{graphicx} % don't load packages more than once
%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % 'amsfonts' is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{newlfont} % seriously?!
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % 't1enc' package is obsolete
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % I bet you the input encoding is 'utf8'
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern} % for characters with well-placed accents

\usepackage{fancybox}
%%\usepackage{xcolor} % don't load packages more than once

\newcommand\encercle[1]{%
    \unitlength1em%
    \begin{picture}(1.5,1.5)%
        \put(0.75,0.3){\circle{1.5}}% modifier 0.3 éventuellement
        \put(0,0){\parbox[b]{1.5em}{\centering#1}}%
    \end{picture}}

%%\usepackage{amssymb} % don't load packages more than once
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{layout} % are you sure you need this?
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{calc}%pour encadrer un paragraphe % are you sure??
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=1.5cm,top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{citeblue}{rgb}{0.00,0.00,0.60}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=citeblue,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}

%------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{\textcircled{\scriptsize #1}}
\makeatother
%------------------------------------------------------------

%%% New code
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for '\patchcmd' macro
\patchcmd\thebibliography{\section*{\refname}}{}{}{}


\begin{document}

\section{Articles préparés pendant la préparation de la thèse}

Durant la préparation de ma thèse, j'ai rédigé et publié 4 articles scientifiques, à savoir: 

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{s1} J.G. Stampfli, The norm of derivation, Pacific J. Math. 33 (1970), no. 3, 737--747.

\bibitem{s2} J.G. Stampfli, The norm of derivation, Pacific J. Math. 33 (1970), no. 3, 737--747.

\end{thebibliography}


\section{Articles publiés ou acceptés pour publication après la soutenance de la thèse}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{s3} J.G. Stampfli, The norm of derivation, Pacific J. Math. 33 (1970), no. 3, 737--747.

\bibitem{s4} J.G. Stampfli, The norm of derivation, Pacific J. Math. 33 (1970), no. 3, 737--747.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```