# Removing gap in references inside block

Tags: bibtex, formatting, beamerposter

How do I remove this large gap right after I begin my references? [image]

I am inside a block environment so I thought this may have had something to do with it. I have attempted to use solutions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498556/how-to-remove-the-space-after-references-bibliography-title) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/691131/delete-the-word-r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rences-and-the-space-before-it) to remove this gap but none of them appear to be working. This is my code below where I allude to the referencing.

```
\begin{block}{{References}}
\nocite{*}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\tiny{\bibliographystyle{abbrv}\bibliography{poster}}
\end{multicols}  
\end{block}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.